# Java statistical packages

Tags: java, statistics

I am searching for java modules which i can include in my program to run various statiscal tests. So far I have found http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html - Are there any other java sites which also supports statistical packages.

I need to incorporate the package in my program and call the functions to run the tests. 
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check this : http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/

and this: http://www.fnordistan.com/jstats.html

Answer (score 8):

Here is one more - https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/ . This library is written completely in Java.

Comment: Any idea how to load a time series into it? The datapoint class needs categorical values and categorical data along w the value of the data point. what are these categorical parameters?